# Clipboard.writeText() does'nt work on Mozilla & IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

I'm using the following function to copy some text to my clipboard:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText('Text to be copied').then(function() {
    console.log('Template copied to clipboard')
}, function() {
    console.log('Unable to write to clipboard. :-(');
});
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't work on Mozilla & IE. It works fine on Chrome.
I've already tried using:

```
Document.execCommand('copy')
```

I found this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi) in developers.google.com, but the example seems to work fine in Chrome and not in other browsers. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Using a not widely supported feature? (It will come in FF63).

Comment: document.execCommand not Document.execCommand. IE has a security zone setting for clipboard access... make sure you are accepting the default IE security zone settings. (Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default". Are you developing/learning using a local html file? or are you using a html file that is on a server or your localhost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not an expert on UI Web Development. 
I've faced a similar situation and I tried to use **Document.execCommand('copy')** as well. It didn't work for me either. 
So, I've made it work both on IE and Chrome like this. I hope this block of code can help you to sort this out.

```
$scope.CopyToClipBoard = function (text) {        
    if (navigator.clipboard != undefined) {//Chrome
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text).then(function () {
            console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
        }, function (err) {
            console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
        });
    }
    else if(window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", text);
    }
};
```

I took the IE solution from here:
[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript#30810322)

Comment: Actually, I've done something similar. But still am not satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.getElementById('copyText');
text.select();  
document.execCommand("copy");
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.